# Is Philosophy "After The Fact" knowledge?

Tags: knowledge

A professor once told me that there is no way to distinguish what is true and what is false in our knowledge except to "see what happens." This seems to imply that the only true knowledge is knowledge of the past.

Yet I thought the whole idea of philosophy, or what used to be called *metaphysics*, is to produce knowledge that is "true," in the sense that it would apply just as well to the future as to the past.

If philosophy is only "after the fact" and cannot tell us anything about the future, is it really useful? Can philosophy provide us with any sort of knowledge about the future? Has the long history of philosophy produced any certainties about what we can expect in the future?

If not, does this mean there is no hope of any true knowledge? If, as philosophy suggests, we are compelled by the love of knowledge and only true knowledge gives true meaning to our lives, has philosophy then left us in a hopeless situation?

Comment: Nothing an no one can tell you what will happen or what is "actually" true, not philosophy, not science, not even faith, because we are human and therefore always fallible. But as autopsies are often useful in preventing future deaths by giving clues about their causes, philosophy can help us reflect on the past to provide some insight into the future, albeit limited and uncertain.

Comment: @Conifold OK, thank you. I guess I will stick with Nonduality.

Comment: 'what used to be called Metaphysics, a kind of "Theory Of Everything" back then' - citation needed on that one. Who claimed that metaphysics was a theory of everything?

Comment: @JamesKingsbery What else would Metaphysics be? Why have it otherwise? Something has to be the "highest form of knowledge", and if so, it must cover everything. If it did not exist, it would be necessary to invent it.

Comment: [Metaphysics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/) is the study of being-as-such, first causes, and, Platonic forms, abstract entities, and the like (although, as the link provided says, an exact definition is hard to provide). It obviously excludes many things, and therefore is not a "theory of everything." But I could be wrong, which is why I asked for a citation :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not appear to be asking a question about philosophy in a way that can be answered (see OPs answer (which OP states is not really an answer) below).

Comment: Per edits. I rarely edit, but since question was being closed and yet had elicited a few answers, why not take a stab it? I am not overly concerned, however, to keep it open.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander very nice rewording, I could not have done better myself. Thank you. **Maybe it will be considered a valid question within or about the field of Philosophy now.** To me, it is the only reasonable place to begin inquiring, because it determines whether I should continue to study Philosophy or not.

Comment: @nocomprende. Well, we'll see if it is released from "hold," I don't get that involved and don't know how these things work. So, you may get further on your next question with careful wording, less first-person, and finishing with a clear question.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen (@NelsonAlexander you can do that as well, there should be a reopen link). I'm wondering however if this is not a duplicate, but don't have the time to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you strive for **proved** knowledge, you must turn to mathematics.
2. If you strive for **confirmed** knowledge, you must turn to natural science.
3. If you strive for the big **questions** asked during millenia by human culture, you must turn to metaphysics.

ad 1: Mathematics and logic are the only disciplines where one can prove the claims. But one has a price to pay: Both are formal sciences and do not deal with the physical world.

ad 2: Natural science deals with the physical world, explaining and making predictions about future observations. But all general theories are hypotheses. They cannot be proved, only falsified or confirmed for single cases (see Popper). In general, scientific theories will be superseded by successor theories.

ad 3: Metaphysics deals with the big questions: Where do we come from? Where do we go? What is man? What about the beginning of the world? And in addition a lot of religious questions.

But the answers given by metaphysicians during the course of time are highly debated. Not alone the theories, but already the concepts can be questioned. For a first introduction see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/

Comment: So it is like the old joke where one Doctor says to another: "When do we get to stop *practicing* medicine and start doing it for real?" When will Philosophy stop *dealing with* the big questions and start *answering* them? It seems that if something is true and properly stated it could no more be argued than any truth of Mathematics: it would impress itself on our minds with such overwhelming force that a counterargument could not arise. This is what I mean by "truth", although it is probably closer to what most people call an experience. Can truth be that hard to figure out?

Comment: @no comprende  "if something is true and properly stated it could no more be argued than any truth of Mathematics: it would impress itself on our minds with such overwhelming force that a counterargument could not arise." Your statement reminds me of Descartes' *clare and distincte* as a truth criterion. Possibly, you enjoy reading his "Discours de la Méthode" (1637) - see chap.2, paragraph 7 - and "Meditationes de prima philosophia" (1641).  But in my opinion, Descartes' criterion is not sufficient. Except from mathematics we do not have access to truth.

Comment: Perhaps Descartes meant that *statements* of truth should be simple and easy to understand, like how Einstein said that one should be able to explain anything to a 6-year old. Explanations that require years of study to understand are not explanations, in my view. I used to discuss programming with my former wife, who had never studied it. She could understand the issues involved.

Comment: @nocomprende Arguably, once a question has a defined, easy-to-explain answer, it leaves the realm of philosophy, and enters the realm of science.  You might view philosophy as exploring the terrain outside of the world of science.  If there was no philosophy, there would never be any new sciences.

Comment: @ChrisSunami "Read my mind: no new sciences!" (Paraphrase of George Bush) ha ha

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge --what it is, how to recognize it, how to certify it --is certainly a major topic ("[Epistemology](http://www.iep.utm.edu/epistemo/)") in philosophy.  However, I've never heard it described as the goal or purpose of most philosophy.  To be technical, the word "philosophy" translates as "the love of wisdom," and knowledge and wisdom are far from synonymous. (*Knowledge* is more having a command of topic-specific facts and skills; *Wisdom* implies making good decisions, being able to see the big picture, the ability to hold fast to what is most fundamental.  One can be wise without being knowledgeable; or knowledgeable without being wise.)

As far as whether we can be *sure* about what is true or not, there are too many different philosophical viewpoints on that to list them all here.  However, there is a good examination of many of the most important viewpoints at the above link.

In general, philosophy tends to be more "skeptical" than science about knowledge.  Quite a large number of major philosophers have essentially agreed with your professor that we can't really "know" anything.  The most significant philosopher who argued that we **can** know things for sure is probably Descartes --you can read his chain of reasoning here in his [Meditations](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/descartes/1639/meditations.htm).

Comment: An interesting field, which is skeptical about knowledge. It reminds me of Paramahansa Yogananda saying that a "Doctor of Divinity" is actually a *Doctor of Delusion*! Perhaps you could add short definitions of Knowledge and Wisdom to your answer to show the contrast? My Guru says that we should strive to be wise, not so much to "have wisdom", which is another distinction. If Philosophers love wisdom, it does not mean that they possess it. So it is more like a hobby than a profession.

Comment: @nocomprende - Added.  And it's true both that many philosophers are lacking in wisdom, and that it isn't, properly speaking, a career.  Those who make a living in the field are quite often "studying" philosophy, not practicing it (yet another distinction)!

Answer (score 1):

What *was called metaphysics* does indeed attempt to predict the future, and often succeeds. When it painstakingly developed methods for doing so rather accurately it was no longer called metaphysics but "physics." The same may be said of psychology, political science, legal theory, logic, computer science, and other fields "seeded" by the long advance and periodic *specialization* of philosophy...or, as you put it, *what was called metaphysics*.

However, once these fruitfully constrained areas of inquiry acquire good methods of prediction and other "useful" practices, the mind is not entirely content to say, well, that's it, everything solved!

When we apply mathematical physics to make and confirm predictions, such as today's confirmation of gravitational waves, there remain such questions as, why does mathematics work like that? How can we arrive at such vast conclusions from a few tiny radio chirps? What in fact should the criteria of such "verifications" or "falsifications"? And so on *ad infinitum*. For physics to claim such a remote finding indicates "reality," for example, is not provable *within physics*, it is a "metaphysical" claim.

And this is only physics, the most robust and independent of such fields. If we generate AI, for example, what do we use as our validating definition of "intelligence"? Not to mention questions of ethics. Why not hurt animals? Or of social systems. On what basis do we say that "democracy" is the best system of government? And so on...

As to the dustbin of history. You want to "predict tomorrow's weather" and don't care about yesterday's. Seems reasonable. But even in science, we do not exactly just "predict the future." We say under special conditions and applications of probability, what has happened in the past, then extrapolate. Without an organized schema of *the past*, we have no more meaningful grasp on the present or future than an Alzheimer's patient. But, then, what sort of schema is best?

Finally, you say philosophy is useless if it cannot tell you the truth. Here enters the ancient, foundational figure of Socrates. There is no problem finding the *truth*. Almost *everybody* will tell you what it is. Truths abound. Plain or fancy. As in science, what is needed is the continual, methodical falsification of the myriad claims to *the truth*, some of them silly, some potentially catastrophic.

Perhaps philosophy cannot present *the truth* on a platter. Perhaps that was a misguided way of approaching the matter, as many philosophers would argue. Instead of viewing philosophy as weather prediction, it may be better to see it more as a an law court, which along with ancient physics was one of its origins. We give "reasons," offer evidence, contest claims, reveal faulty logic, and attempt to arrive at *judgments*... about many things, including possibly the future.

Hegel said famously "the Owl of Minerva flies only at dusk." The symbol of the goddess of wisdom can only rise with a retrospective view of history and past, looking back. But in a sense, science does something similar only in a far more constrained way. Philosophy enables you to compare the "reality that surrounds you" with something else, integrating past and future into some reasoned order. So even if can't accurately predict the future, we don't have to look at the past or present, in our hasty, quotidian frame of mind, and think: What the F**k just happened?

Comment: +1 for: "*what is needed is the continual, methodical falsification of the myriad claims to the truth*". I think that is called Self Inquiry, which leads to Nonduality. I am pragmatic, I'm just looking for a "good enough" prediction and then I will be happy to say "*everything solved!*" Hasn't that at least been achieved by now? Is there some subset that all the arguers agree on?

Comment: There are negative agreements on what no longer makes sense, like foundational ideas of "first causes" or "truth." Certain problems in logic and language are much better understood. But we do not live in a static social or material world. New technology, like the nuclear bomb or AI, will raise new questions, as will new social platforms, like the "nation state." As long as we are "human" it never ends in a final "rule book," but no individual human need bother themselves with the particular literature of philosophy.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that Philosophical questions would be the most important, so would require study and self-examination. (Else life not worth living... I sense a bootstrap here... Pirsig saying "Worth is a Quality term"... Infinite Regress? hmm.) I like the idea of agreements on what no longer makes sense. Self Inquiry pretty much dispenses with *everything*, eventually. What emerges is not subject to discourse. I wonder if Nonduality belongs in Philosophy? Kierkegaard was so close.

Answer (score 0):

Heidegger in his lectures on Aristotles philosophy wrote:

> Greek philosophy started in greatness, continued in greatness and ended in greatness.

He was referring to the period from the presocratics Parmenides to Aristotle; a great deal of this was metaphysics - but not all; and it's worth pondering on the physics part of metaphysics...

Comment: @no comprendre: Plato supposed it to be the iniquitous influence of sophistry; at least, later, there was the *renaissance* - ie  re-birth; first in Islam, and then in Italian Christiandom.

Comment: I always thought it interesting that Plato decried his teacher Socrates as a Sophist (was it a negative term then?) and Aristotle wrote it all down and restored Socrates to greatness. Plato never wrote anything, did he? I guess the clash of ideas was intended to bring forth creative understanding.

Comment: @no comprende: don't really follow you, it doesn't seem grounded in any thing like the usual readings of Ancient Greek philosophy; if you want a debate/discussion/or just toss off words there are better sites to go to.

Comment: No I actually read that somewhere: debate and argument bring out more knowledge and understanding. This is why they have debate clubs in schools, and why you have to defend your thesis (or political stance) before other people. If we don't do that here, well, maybe we won't have the best ideas? If all answers were the same, what is the point? I may be bad at arguing, but that does not make arguing bad. (I think that is a sound argument...)